# Simple math program wont work?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a `batch` program that will add the input to 232, then divide the result by 470. It would also be nice if someone told me how to make it so that if the user inputs a letter instead of a number, or an invalid character, anything besides a number, the program would execute a "goto command." Thanks!

PS the current code outputs 0, regardless of input.

Heres my code:

```
@echo off
title Grade
:1
cls
set /p input= "Grade: "
set /a input1= input + 232
set /a input2= input1 / 470
echo %input2%
pause
goto 1
```

Comment: I cannot see any errors in the code, it should work as it is. Are you expecting to receive floating-point numbers? `set /A` supports signed 32-bit arithmetics only. I guess you are receiving `0` because of the integer division; so you need to enter a huge number to get something other than `0`...

Comment: Concerning wrong user inputs: 1. to capture empty input: `set "input="` before `set /P`, then `if not defined input goto somewhere` after `set /P` (note that `set /P` keeps the former value in case you just press *enter*); 2. if you place `set /A input+=0` after `set /P`, the input is converted to a number (`0` if non-numeric); 3. you could compare the original input with the one converted to a number (like in 2.) using [`if`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) and go to elsewhere if not equal...

Comment: @DavidPostill, the `%` signs are *not* required for [`set /A`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html); so `set /A y=%x%+1` and `set /A y=x+1` are somewhat equivalent...

Comment: @aschipfl Oh. (egg on face) You're right :/

Answer (score 0):

For your division equation, batch files do not support floating point arithmetic, so you won't get a true answer.  Anything less than 238 for input returns a 0 for your quotient.

Here's some code to let you see how to guarantee numeric input.

```
:Blurb
   @Echo off
   Cls
   Echo Grade Math
:GetNum
   Echo.
   Set /p _Input="Grade: "
   Set "_Num="
   For /f "delims=0123456789" %%i in ("%_Input%") Do Set "_Num=%%i"
   If Defined _Num Echo.&Echo Invalid: please enter a number.&Goto :GetNum
:DoMath
   Set /a _Sum= _Input + 232
   Echo Sum = %_Sum%
   Set /a _Quotient= _Sum / 470
   Echo Quotient = %_Quotient%
   Pause
   Goto :GetNum
:End
```